# Local mail server not working prpoperly in centos 6.5

Tags: smtp, sendmail, mail-server, dovecot

I want to setup a local mail server which want to work in local environment. For that i used the sendmail and dovecot. 
i have a development server and in that we uses mantis like tools. so after resolving the issue each developer got the mail previously but now it is not getting in local intranet.

so i need to resolve this problem for that i installed sendmail server.

yum install sendmail* -y
yum install m4* -y

changed in sendmail.mc

dnl # DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.1.91, Name=MTA')dnl

then

m4  /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf

then service sendmail restart

for receiving mail i installed dovecot

yum install dovecot* -y

in that i changed

in dovecot.conf

uncomment pop3 imap

10-auth.conf

changed

disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login

in 10-mailconf

uncomment the mailDir.

in 10-master.conf

user and group left blank

everything is works all said ok.
sendmail ok. dovecot ok.
no error but mail dosen't receive.
but nothing happened i am not able to receive mail.

I need to do like if i have a email user1@example.com and user2@example.com so both are using mantis user1 is admin of mantis. if any issue get resolve then user2 will get the automatic mail for that from user1.

for that how i configure the mail server.

Comment: Follow this guide to get mail working on CentOS https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos#head-0facb50d5796bee0bd394636c32ffa9a997a6ab5

Answer (score 0):

In `sendmail.mc` change

```
dnl # DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.1.91, Name=MTA')dnl
```

to

```
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Port=smtp, Addr=192.168.0.0, Name=MTA')dnl
```

To accept mail on port 25 from local address 192.168.xxx.xxx

Also add a line in access file (to relay mail from those IP's):

```
Connect:192.168         RELAY
```

Don't forget to type `make` after editing.